# Swift 5.1 & Alamofire 5.1 : GET method ERROR

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, afnetworking, alamofire-request

when passing header and params: Alamofire.AFError.URLRequestValidationFailureReason.bodyDataInGETRequest(0 bytes)

```
 AF.request(urlString,method:.get, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in

              print(response)

 }
```

Comment: share any code related to this problem please

Comment: We need code to help...

Answer (score 1):

As of Apple's 2019 OS versions, trying to make a GET request with body data will fail with an error. The value must be `nil`. Alamofire provides it's own error here in order to provide a consistent experience for Alamofire users, regardless of which OS their code is running on.